# Client connect error in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I tried to call WL.Client.connect I get an error response saying "Connection in Progress". I am using here 7.0. Why is this happening? Any insights on this?

Comment: May we see the server log that capture this event?

Comment: i got this error only in iphone7-iOS 10.3.3. on launching the app, when i call connect() method. I think we have to give a timeout ... i will try this tomorrow. if you find any fix, let me know too.

Comment: or we can ignore Connection in progress error code based on the scenario.

Comment: If you put a debug line in the method where you have wl.client.connect(), do you see it appearing twice?